# Three Variable Equation Word Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

A friend e-mails you the results of a recent high school swim meet. The e-mail states that 24 individuals placed, earning a combined total of 53 points. First place earned 3 points, second place earned 2 points, and third place earned 1 point. There were as many first-placed finishers as second-and third-place finishers combined.

1) Write a system of three equations that represents how many people finished in each place.

2) How many swimmers finished in first place, second place, and third place?

I believe the hardest thing for me here is figuring out what the three equations are.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ denote the amount of swimmers who placed $1^{st}, 2^{nd}, \verb" and " 3^{rd}$ respectively.  Translating the email into equations we get:

24 individuals placed 
$\Rightarrow x + y + z = 24$  (1)

earning a combined total of 53 (3 points awarded for 1st, 2 for 2nd, 1 for 3rd). $\Rightarrow 3x + 2y +1z = 53$ (2)

There were as many first-placed finishers as second-and third-place finishers combined.
$\Rightarrow x = y + z$ (3)

Solving (3) for $z$ and then substituting into (1), we get $x + y + z = x + y + (x - y)  = 2x = 24 \Rightarrow x = 12$

Now subtracting (1) from (2), we get $2x+ y = 29 \Rightarrow y = 29 - 2(12) = 29-24 = 5$
Then from (3), $z = 12 - 5 =7$.

Comment: I understand everything here except for the last step where you got z. Sorry, but could you try to explain why you did these steps?

Answer (score 0):

$x$, $y$ and $z$ (or your three variables) represent, like the question said, the number of people that finished in each place ($x$=1st,$y$=2nd,$z$=3rd).

So $x+y+z$ has to equal 24, because that is how many people total there is.

Next, you can base the other equations on how many points each got, so the number of points the $x$ group got would be $3x$, because there were x people in first place, gaining 3 points per person.

I think you can get the last one.

I hope that helps!